# How to access nested arrays in a JSON object (Android)

Tags: android, arrays, json, object, nested

The structure of my JSON is,

```
"posts":[
    //Post 1.        
    {
        "images":{
            "small":{
                "url": "http://..."
                "width": 64
            },
            "large":{
                "url": "http://..."
                "width": 128
            }
        },

        "caption":"..."
    },

    {
        //Post 2
        "images":{
            "small":{
                "url": "http://..."
                "width": 64
            },
            "large":{
                "url": "http://..."
                "width": 128
            }
        },

        "caption":"..."

     } 
]
```

I want to get, *posts -> images -> large -> url* from each post in the form of a string.

Here's what I've done:

```
JSONArray jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("posts");

for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONArray innerArray1 = jsonobject.getJSONArray("images");
    JSONArray innerArray2 = innerArray1.getJSONArray(0);    //gets "large"
    JSONArray innerArray3 = innerArray2.getJSONArray(1);    //gets "url"
    String finalString = innerArray3.toString();
}
```

I expected the value of "url" in finalString, except it ends up being empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"images", "small", "large" are **JSONObjects**(notice the curly braces), not JSONArrays(square brackets) and you need to extract them as such.

```
JSONArray jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("posts");

for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject innerObject1 = jsonobject.getJSONObject("images");
    JSONObject innerObject2 = innerObject1.getJSONObject("large");    //gets "large"
    String finalString = innerObject2.getString("url");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use Retrofit and GSON

Build a few model classes called `Posts.java` `Post.java` `Image.java`

**Posts.java**

```
public class Posts {

   @SerializedName("posts")
   private List<Post> mPosts;
   public List<Post> getPosts() {
        return mPosts;
   }

}
```

**Post.java**

```
public class Post {

   @SerializedName("image")
   private Image mImage;
   public Image getImage() {
        return mImage;
   }

   @SerializedName("caption")
   public String mCaption;
   public String getCaption() {
       return mCaption;
   }

}
```

**Image.java**

```
public class Image {

   @SerializedName("small")
   private String mSmallImageUrl;
   public Image getSmallImageUrl() {
        return mSmallimageUrl;
   }

   @SerializedName("large")
   public String mLargeImageUrl;
   public String getLargeImageUrl() {
       return mLargeImageUrl;
   }

}
```

The `SerializedName` annotation is from the `GSON` library which should already be part of the Android Studio library packages which you can implement.

It actually creates `POJO` objects for you all you have to do is create model classes.

With retrofit the implementation is simple in that you declare a `RestAdapter` somewhere like so:

```
public class Client {

        public static final String API_URL = ".......";

        // Constructor which you can initialize somewhere else.
        public Client() {

                RestAdapter mAsyncRestAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                                     .setEndpoint(API_URL)
                                     .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()))
                                     .build();

        }

        // Implement Interfaces here somewhere. 

}
```

Then create interfaces for your api endpoints like so, this helps decouple things. Note the `GET` annotation is from retrofit. Retrofit also allows `POST` `PUT` `DELETE` etc.:

```
public interface IPosts {

     @GET("/posts")
     void getPosts(Callback<Posts> callback);

}
```

Notice that `Callback` is a retrofit callback and upon a `200 OK` status it would grab the `Response` from the API and convert the `JSON` into the `Posts` object with GSON.

You would implement the interface like so:

```
public void getPosts(Callback<Posts> callback) {
    IPosts posts = mAsyncRestAdapter.create(IPosts.class);
    posts.getPosts(callback);
}
```

Somewhere in your app just create the following callback:

```
Callback<Posts> callback = new Callback<Posts>() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Posts posts, Response response) {
        // Do whatever you want with posts here
        List<Post> posts = posts.getPosts(); // Get posts for example

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(RetrofitError error) {
        // Handle the error

    }

};

// Pass this callback to the implementation of the interface to have it actually work
mClient.getPosts(callback);
```

This is one way in which you can easily access nested JSON objects. Retrofit with GSON is a true pleasure to use. The beauty of this method is that all you have to do is define callbacks, interfaces, and models. From which you can see the code is very minimal and decoupled.

Comment: Although I implemented Bidhan's method for now, thank you for introducing me to GSON. Will definitely come in handy in the future!

Comment: no worries, if you end up using this method let me know how it goes

Comment: too add more beauty is to use this site to automatically convert json string to pojo : http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/